# My toggle bolt hole hit a stud. What do I do now?

Tags: bathroom, sink

I'm installing a pedestal sink and was screwing a hole for the toggle bolt and ended up hitting a stud. Now I have this hole I can't use for the toggle bolt, and I'm stumped on what to do. What's the best solution?

Comment: Do you have to use the toggle bolt?  Usually, people are happy to hit a stud... I've used in the past, a "[stud solver](http://www.homedepot.com/p/E-Z-Ancor-Stud-Solver-7-x-1-1-4-in-Phillips-Zinc-Plated-Flat-Head-Drywall-Anchors-50-Pack-25316/100391938)".

Comment: Those stud solvers @MaximeMorin mentions are awesome! But if the hole isn't too big in diameter, you may be able to just use a lag screw or even a wood screw. You can look up a pilot hole chart to be sure.

Comment: Rejoice that your sink is going to be anchored the way it should be, and use a lag bolt.

Comment: @Doresoom Yes, I should have mentioned that I've used them for hanging stuff but not for a sink... :)

Answer (score 26):

That sounds like a good problem to have. Go to the store and get a lag screw, and use that instead.

[image: Lag Screws]
<sub>(source: [china-ogpe.com](http://image.china-ogpe.com/pimage/1099/image/Hex_lag_screw_Product1099.jpg))</sub>

Attaching the sink to a stud is preferable, and will offer a more solid install.

Hanging a sink from drywall, sounds like a bad idea to begin with. So I'd say you got lucky to hit the stud.

Comment: Please go with Testors advice, do be careful to not tighten the lag too tight though it will crack the sink at the mounting hole. Barely snug is all you need, just enough to kep the washer you use with it from moving, no more

Answer (score 3):

You need a basin fixing kit. Like this one....

[image: Common basin fixing kit]

Screw the coarse threaded part into the stud using a spanner or pair of grips after drilling a suitable sized pilot hole. Slide the basin over the protruding threads, use the plastic washers, followed by the metal ones and nip up the nut gently until just holding. The plastic plugs are there for masonry walls only.